# How to set column widths with xlwt python

Tags: python, xlwt

I simply need to set the width of a specific cell in a spreadsheet to a hardcoded value with `xlwt`.

I have tried searching this but I still cannot find a straightforward answer to what attribute to apply to the `Workbook` object

For example:

```py
wb = Workbook()
checklist = wb.add_sheet("checklist ")

checklist.write(0, 0, "item")

checklist.width(x)
```

That's it, all I need the the attribute for that last line, this is a simple enquiry but I just cannot find a simple answer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to do the next code?

```
checklist.col(col_index).width  = 1000
```